# Denseness: $\overline{\mathcal{l}^2_0}=\mathcal{l}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the finite sequences are indeed dense within the space?

Comment: Write down the definition of convergence of a series and stare at it very hard.

Comment: Haha thx ^^ too easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a series $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty$$
then the definition of convergence implies that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that
$$\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \epsilon$$

Now given the sequence $s = (a_1, a_2, ...) \in \ell^2$, form the sequence $s_N = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_N, 0, \dots)$ and note that
$$\|s - s_N\|_{\ell^2} < \epsilon$$